# Internally which file/page wil be execute first in php

Tags: php

I am new to php, so i dont know the framework clearly. In PHP project/application which file/page will execute first.

Comment: What do you mean by `internally`?

Answer (score 3):

There's no first executed file or whatsoever. The php file **you** execute gets executed that's it. In web environment you execute a file by requesting the web server using a regular browser for example, when your browser doesn't specify a file name to execute (for example: http://some_address.com/file_to_execute.php) the web server usually assumes you're requesting the so called home page (ie. index.php) but this is just by design, the home page could even be **home.php** or **whatever.php** depending on your web server configuration.

Other than that, your question is murky and if this isn't the answer you're requesting, then re-work your question.

Comment: Ok. I have made login.php as first page in that i am using the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. And its working fine in browser but its giving error in debugging mode as "$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] not set". So whats may be the problem

Comment: What do you call debugging mode? What web server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Usually either default.php or index.php depending on your server configuration.

But you can change it however you want: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/directive-dict.html (on apache)

Comment: Ok. I have made login.php as first page in that i am using the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. And its working fine in browser but its giving error in debugging mode as "$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] not set". So whats may be the problem

Answer (score 0):

it's depend on the apache configuration which file should be executed when you enter url but do not defined the file name in url. Then the file named in the apache configuration will be executed.

The apache configuration file called `httpd.conf`

In this file there is a line called  `DirectoryIndex  somefile.php someotherfile.php`

That decide which file will be executed first.

If the `somefile.php` is not exists in the hierarchy of your directories then `somotherfile.php` will be exeucted.

These all are in the case when you did not defined the file name in the URL in the address bar of browser.

Comment: Ok. I have made login.php as first page in that i am using the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. And its working fine in browser but its giving error in debugging mode as "$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] not set". So whats may be the problem